# H-space and fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have a certain pointed path-connected topological space $X$, and a natural map $\mu : X \times X \to X$. I want to prove it is $H$-space. So I need to prove that maps $\mu(x_0,-)$ and $\mu(-,x_0)$ are homotopic to identity, where $x_0$ is base point of $X$.

In a reference I am reading, author says that proof follows from following fact: there is subspace $Y \subset X$ which is path-connected and contains base point $x_0$, and whose fundamental group, which is identified with commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$, is trivial.

Of course, this implies that fundmanetal group of $X$ is abelian. But I don't understand why this implies $X$ is H-space. Is this clear from the given data, or maybe something specific of my space $X$?

Edit: It is obvious that not any arbitrary map $\mu$ will give an $H$-space. I guess the author means that the facts given make it somehow easier to check that $\mu$ is unital multiplication. Probably, they reduce it to some trivial verifications. But I am not sure why.

Comment: There is no reason that the data you have given turn $X$ into a $H$-space. Consider the constant map $\mu(x,y) = x_0$... It's also not clear what the relation between $Y$ and $\mu$ is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks for comment, pls see edit.